# Squid and OpenVPN slow on OpenVZ?

Tags: openvpn, vps, squid, openvz

I have two vps, one on OVH with KVM, the second on another hosting with OpenVZ. On OVH the speed is ok with squid and openvpn, i reach 100mbit (max speed of my connection), but i have a problem with the second vps. My internet speed is limited to 30mbit when i use Squid and OpenVPN, but only in browser (Chrome and Firefox). If i use torrent, Steam, IDM (Internet Download Manager) or other, i reach the max speed. I have asked to my hosting provider, he have said "It's a bug of OpenVZ, you don't have this problem on OVH because is virtualized with KVM". It's true?

OpenVPN conf per both VPS

```
port 62826
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_hVVe1BJQj2YiiRCh.crt
key server_hVVe1BJQj2YiiRCh.key 
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 0
```

Even for squid the conf is the same for both VPS. Default conf, i have only changed the default port and added these lines:

```
acl kiryu src MY IP
http_access allow kiryu
tcp_outgoing_address SERVER IP (CENSORED)
udp_outgoing_address SERVER IP (CENSORED)
visible_hostname kiryu
access_log none
cache_store_log none
cache_log /dev/null
httpd_suppress_version_string on
dns_v4_first on
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I am not surprised. OpenVZ is very old container-like technology, not true virtual machines.